# Making the countdown timer resist page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

good day good people. I have been working on a countdown timer using php, mysql, javascript and ajax. the timer is working but when the page is refreshed it restarts i don't know where i went wrong.

my timer function:

```
public function timer(){
    $this->getServer();
    $t = 45;
    $duration = "";
    try{
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->serverName;dbname=$this->serverDatabase",$this->serverUsername,$this->serverPassword);
        $time = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM duration WHERE duration='$t'");
        $time->execute();

        if($time->rowCount()>=1){

           while($rows = $time->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $duration = $rows["duration"];
           } 
        }
    $_SESSION["duration"] = $duration;
    $_SESSION["start_time"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $end_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["duration"].'minutes', strtotime($_SESSION["start_time"])));

    $_SESSION["end_time"] = $end_time; 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){

        die($e->getMessage());
    }    
}

test.php

session_start();
    require_once("connections.php");
    require_once("secure.php");

    $timer = new main();
    $timer->setServer($serverName,$serverDatabase,$serverUsername,$serverPassword);
    $timer->getServer();
    $timer->timer();
?>

<div id="response"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function()
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "response.php", false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    },1000);
</script>
response.php

<?php
session_start();

$from_time1=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$to_time1= $_SESSION["end_time"];

$timeFirst=strtotime($from_time1);
$timeSecond=strtotime($to_time1);

$differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond-$timeFirst;

echo gmdate("H:i:s",$differenceInSeconds);
?>
```

i will be glad if someone helps me figure out where i am getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to test to see if `$_SESSION['start_time']` already exists. If it does, use that value to calculate against based on the present time and continue the countdown.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['start_time'])){
  //calculate time left
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not over writing your session variable again?